# Compressed string length somewhat greater than original string length?

Tags: java, string, compression

I've created an application for compressing and decompressing the string using inflator and deflator. The application is working properly when tested on simple word statements and getting compressed into a string whose length is smaller than original string length,but the problem is when I tries using encrypted string I'm getting the compressed string length somewhat greater than original string length.
Can anyone please tell me some solution of this?

```
    private String compress(String stringToCompress) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        byte[] compressedData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] stringAsBytes = stringToCompress.getBytes("UTF-8");

        Deflater compressor = new Deflater();
        compressor.setInput(stringAsBytes);
        compressor.finish();
        int compressedDataLength = compressor.deflate(compressedData);

        byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOf(compressedData, compressedDataLength);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
    }

    private String decompressToString(String base64String) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, DataFormatException
    {
        byte[] compressedData = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);

        Inflater deCompressor = new Inflater();
        deCompressor.setInput(compressedData, 0, compressedData.length);
        byte[] output = new byte[102400];
        int decompressedDataLength = deCompressor.inflate(output);
        deCompressor.end();

        return new String(output, 0, decompressedDataLength, "UTF-8");
    }
```

**WHEN**

```
public static void main(String[] args)    
        {
         Sample_class = new Sample_class();
         S String strToBeCompressed  = "Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai nayaPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai nayaPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai nayaPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya intezaar Kar loon main kPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya intezaar Kar loon main kya apna haal Aye dil-e-bekaraar Mere dil-e-bekaraar Tu hi bata Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Udta hi firoon in hawaon mein kahin Ya main jhool jaoon in ghataon mein kahin Udta hi firoon in hawaon mein kahin Ya main jhool jaoon in ghataon mein kahin ";

         System.out.println(strToBeCompressed);
         String compressedData  = m.compress(strToBeCompressed);
         String deCompressedString = m.decompressToString(compressedData);
         System.out.println("Original     :: " + strToBeCompressed.length());
         System.out.println("Compressed   :: " + compressedData.toString().length());
         System.out.println("decompressed :: " + deCompressedString.length());
        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai nayaPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai nayaPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai nayaPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya intezaar Kar loon main kPehla nasha Pehla khumaar Naya pyaar hai naya intezaar Kar loon main kya apna haal Aye dil-e-bekaraar Mere dil-e-bekaraar Tu hi bata Pehla nasha Pehla khumaar Udta hi firoon in hawaon mein kahin Ya main jhool jaoon in ghataon mein kahin Udta hi firoon in hawaon mein kahin Ya main jhool jaoon in ghataon mein kahin 
Original     :: 980
Compressed   :: 212
decompressed :: 980
```

**BUT WHEN**

```
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {
     Sample_class = new Sample_class();
     String strToBeCompressed = "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";

     System.out.println(strToBeCompressed);
     String compressedData  = m.compress(strToBeCompressed);
     String deCompressedString = m.decompressToString(compressedData);
     System.out.println("Original     :: " + strToBeCompressed.length());
     System.out.println("Compressed   :: " + compressedData.toString().length());
     System.out.println("decompressed :: " + deCompressedString.length());
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
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
Original     :: 1032
Compressed   :: 1076
decompressed :: 1032
```

Answer (score 1):

Data compression takes advantage of patterns within the data that can be encoded using a shorter pattern. This works on the assumption that the patterns exist. If no patterns are found, a perfect compression scheme would leave the data untouched. Unfortunately most compression schemes will add a small amount of meta-data to at least define the scheme for example. What you are seeing is probably this situation.

Imagine attempting to compress already-compressed data. Surely you would not expect this to further decrease it's size.

Comment: is there any solution for this......since the thing is that i convert a file into a compressed string with a shorter length and then send them from a server to client and where at the client it decompressed it into original string and convert into the specified file.

Comment: There is not - this should be a rare situation that will only happen with certain patterns of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem to solve.

You are providing input that is Base-64 encoded.  That should be compressible, and in fact it is compressible.  You should be seeing those 1032 Base-64 characters compressed down to about 800 bytes (`compressedDataLength`).

But then you turn around and expand it again by Base-64 encoding the binary compressed data, getting back where you started, with a little expansion.

Base-64 encoding will always expand the data by a factor of 4/3.  So if you did not get a compression factor of at least 3/4, then you will see overall expansion.

Furthermore, even without the Base-64 encoding, there will be data that is expanded by compression, such as already-compressed data.  It is unavoidable that lossless compression will expand for some inputs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The main question for user3159579 is why whould you send a file in base64? Try using binary streams instead.

Answer (score 0):

well you are base64 encoding the deflated bytes. that can add a few more things. The best way to work with such things is byte[] and snot strings. convert to bytes, stream them where you want and reconstruct back your resource/string from byte[].

Comment: since the thing is that i convert a file into a compressed string with a shorter length and then send them from a server to client and where at the client it decompressed it into original string and convert into the specified file.

Comment: why not just deflate the file stream itself and send it across? why convert it to a String and then work. Deflate and inflate semantics dont work well with character based streams but are designed for byte based stream.

Comment: have a looky at Deflater OutputStream and InputStream and same for Inflator one also.

Comment: can you please give me a sample example